# AI DJ app that will do a reasonably smooth transition from one song to another?

Tags: music, artificial-intelligence

AI explosion, so many new tools.

I tried to search for DJ-ing software but they are sophisticated, too many buttons, not something I can do on my iPhone in the middle of the party.

Inspiration: Decentralized Dance Party https://theddp.com

Use case: crowd is raving, next song is lined up, anything reasonable is orders of magnitude better than boring outro / intro of a song...

Comment: You might want to look into https://slipmat.io/ I can not recommend specifically, since I am not into DJ'ing but it sounds promising.